# How using If with background button in kotlin android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want use (If) with background button for check from name the image inside button in kotlin android
I did using  button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1) but can't using it with If
I used

```
If (button1.background == R.drawable.image1){
button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2)
}
```

and so I used

```
If (button1.background == @drawable/image1){
button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2)
}
```

but all error
what is solve ?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: If is not valid keyword in Kotlin. Try 'if' instead.

Comment: Kotlin is case-sensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to compare `button1` background to another resource in *drawable* folder.

Here is a solution:

```
if (button1.background.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.image1).constantState) {
    button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2)
}
```

If you want to use this code in a Fragment

```
if (button1.background.constantState == ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.image1).constantState) {
    button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2)
}
```